# Can I use the Azure web app service for PHP and NodeJs both in the same application?

Tags: php, node.js, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

Can I use the Azure web app service for PHP and NodeJs both in the same application?
Following are my PHP Web app requirements. So can I used the Azure Web app service or need to deploy it on LAMP stack VMs only?

[image]

Comment: Does this help: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/multi-language-azure-web-sites-with-php-node-and-dotnet/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Virtual Applications` to achieve the functions you want.

[image]

**Prompt:**

1. You web app should use windows platform.
2. The main application cannot be a nodejs application.
3. Ensure that each application can be deployed successfully (to ensure that the application can run normally), learn to use the web.config configuration file.

   [image]

Comment: "Your web app should use windows platform."But my application needs Linux so is it feasible for me to use the Azure Web App service or I need to deploy on Azure VMs which I don't want to so is there any other workaround?

Comment: @AshishKarpe From the official documentation, there is no solution on azure. You can consult the Azure official by raising a support ticket.